# What is advantages of using ob_start() over don't using it?

Tags: php

What is advantages of using ob_start()? What is its effects on performance? Say i have this code:

```
echo 'hello';
echo 'world';
```

compare to:

```
ob_start();
echo 'hello';
echo 'world';
ob_end_flush();
```

Which one has best performance and why?

Comment: Why don't you benchmark it and see?

Comment: I did it. it show nothing. Document size and response time is vary in both code. I want to know if they are different on server side.

Comment: It's not used for performance. It's used to manipulate the output buffer in various ways, such as capturing some output to a variable, or holding off output until all HTTP headers are set. Frameworks tend to make extensive use of this feature.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The effect on performance is negligible.

Normally PHP renders line by line as instructions are executed. however once you have output buffering turned on by using `ob_start()` it means that php will buffer the output and not render it until you hit `ob_end_flush()`

This is used in case you need to do more processing before sending down the output to the client.

However...

Although output buffering does not affect the performance, you can use it cleverly to increase your website performance. have a look at [here](https://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html)